# Approximating $ e^{\sin(x)} $

Tags: calculus

I know that

$$ e^{\sin(x)} = 1 + \sin(x) + {\sin^2x \over 2} + {\sin^3x \over 6} + B\sin^4x $$

I also know that $$ \sin(x) = x-{x^3 \over 6}+Bx^5 $$

I know I should probably just plug in the approximation for $ \sin(x) $ in the first equation, but it get's really messy, and I feel there should be an easier way?

I've recently started learning about Maclaurin series, so forgive me if this is a silly question. I'm just very confused on how I should approach problems like these.

Comment: It's the natural, and perhaps easiest, way. Especially if you're required only to give a third order (say) approximation.

Comment: For a way to write the general term (not necessarily pretty) you can use the Faa di Bruno formula for the successive derivatives of a composition. The derivatives give you the coefficients. The case of $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$ will be slightly nicer since their successive derivatives cycle.

Comment: What domain do you need an approximation over?  Only a real interval?  In that case the periodicity of $\sin x$ is inherited by $e^{\sin x}$.  What accuracy is needed?  There are algorithms for finding the best polynomial approximation on a bounded interval, e.g. for the least uniform-norm error.

Comment: FWIW, there are no further details given. When I look at other examples from the book, it says to give an appropriate order approximation. Thanks for your answers, I will look into them!

Comment: Alternatively, you can calculate the first three derivatives of $e^{\sin x}$ and evaluate them at zero. For me at least it is less likely to be error prone than taking powers of cubic polynomials or implementing Faa di Bruno.

Comment: Bear in mind you can simplify early, to retain only the higher terms; e.g. sin-x-squared is just x^2 - (1/3)x^4, if you are only keeping terms up to x^5. Rather than expand it all and then simplify after.

Comment: See [OEIS A$047687$](http://oeis.org/A047687) and [OEIS A$047688$](http://oeis.org/A047688).

Comment: Neither of your equalities are true. (Also you use the letter $B$ in both equations even though the values represented in the two equations are different. You need to use different letters.) You need to mention that the equalities hold *up to a degree*. Also presumably you're not trying to find the *entire* Maclaurin expansion of $\exp\sin x$, only a few terms. If that's so, then you should *say how many terms you need*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an exam, in Calculus, all you will probably need from that function is a few terms of its Taylor. For this just take, as you were doing, the series of $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$ and compose them to compute the first few terms.

For fun and culture let's compute the general term.

Let's recall the Faa di Bruno's formula:

> **Faa di Bruno's formula:** 
>   $$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}g(f(x))=\sum\frac{m!}{b_1!b_2!...b_m!}g^{(k)}(f(x))\left(\frac{f'(x)}{1!}\right)^{b_1}\left(\frac{f''(x)}{2!}\right)^{b_2}...\left(\frac{f^{(m)}(x)}{m!}\right)^{b_m}$$
>   where the sum is over all different solutions in non-negative integers $b_1,b_2,...,b_m$ of $b_1+2b_2+...+mb_m=m$ and $k=b_1+b_2+...+b_m$.

In our case $g(x)=e^x$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$, and we are interested in derivatives at $x=0$.

This means that $g^{(k)}(f(0))=e^{\sin(0)}=1$. Also, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ when $n$ is even and $=(-1)^{n-1}$ when $n$ is odd.

Therefore we get

$$e^{\sin(x)}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_m}{m!}x^m$$

where

$$a_m:=\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\left(e^{\sin(x)}\right)|_{x=0}=\\=\sum\frac{m!}{b_1!b_3!...b_{2[m/2]}!}\left(\frac{(-1)^{1-1}}{1!}\right)^{b_1}\left(\frac{(-1)^{3-1}}{3!}\right)^{b_3}...\left(\frac{(-1)^{2[m/2]-1}}{(2[m/2])!}\right)^{b_{2[m/2]}}$$

and $b_1+3b_3+...+2[m/2]b_{2[m/2]}=m$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all of that! Frankly, at the moment, I do not understand much of it, but I'm def going to read up on it!

Comment: @user1904218 I imagine you are a calculus student. The best idea for you, in an exam would be to compose the series open parentheses and compute the first few terms. This answer is more for culture than anything else. To be aware of the Faa di Bruno formula for the derivatives of a composition.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am a calculus student :) However, I do enjoy math, and learning new things is always interesting. I really appreciate ALL replies I get, so thanks again!